# parseInt inside Java inside html

Tags: java, javascript, html, import, parseint

We have a calendar with some custom views. Our views are loaded in a calendar component (inside a div). This calendar component has a js file that loads html templates.

This is the method that load the templates:

```
Calendar.prototype._loadTemplate = function(name) {
     if(this.options.templates[name]) {
            return;
     }
     var self = this;
     $.ajax({
            url:      self._templatePath(name),
            dataType: 'html',
            type:     'GET',
            async:    false,
            cache:    this.options.tmpl_cache
     }).done(function(html) {
            self.options.templates[name] = _.template(html);
     });
};
```

This works fine with templates without parameters.

But now, we want to pass a parameter to the template. The parameter pass through fine, but we want to parse it as int (as it comes as string).

This is how the template file looks like (cal.totalContractWeeks is the parameter):

```
<% import java.lang.Integer; %>

<div class="cal-year-box">
   <div class="row row-fluid cal-before-eventlist colgrid">
   <% t = Integer.parseInt(cal.totalContractWeeks); %>
   <% imax = t; %>
   <% jmax = 10; %>
   <% i = 0; %> 
   <% j = jmax ; %>
   <% while(i <= imax) { %>
         <div class="span3 col-md-1 cal-cell" data-cal-row="-week<%= j%>" style="background-color: <%= cal._weekContractEventStatusColor(i) %>" ><%= cal._weekContract(i) %>
         <% i ++; %>
         <% j ++; %>         
   </div>
         <% if (j > jmax) { %>
   </div>
   <div class="row row-fluid cal-before-eventlist colgrid">
         <% j = 1; %>
         <% } %>      
   <% } %>
   </div>
</div>
```

But this throw us an "Unexpected reserved word" error.

What are we doing wrong? Can you help us, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasn't that cal.totalContractWeeks was a string, but is wasn't being filled at first load (forcing second load of the template works fine).
So we created an auxiliar function to retrieve the updated value expected from cal.totalContractWeeks.

Here is how the template looks now:

```
<div class="cal-year-box">
   <div class="row row-fluid cal-before-eventlist colgrid">
   <% t = cal._getTotalContractWeeks(); %>
   <% imax = t; %>
   <% jmax = 10; %>
   <% i = 0; %> 
   <% j = jmax ; %>
   <% while(i <= imax) { %>
         <div class="span3 col-md-1 cal-cell" data-cal-row="-week<%= j%>" style="background-color: <%= cal._weekContractEventStatusColor(i) %>" ><%= cal._weekContract(i) %>
         <% i ++; %>
         <% j ++; %>         
   </div>
         <% if (j > jmax) { %>
   </div>
   <div class="row row-fluid cal-before-eventlist colgrid">
         <% j = 1; %>
         <% } %>      
   <% } %>
   </div>
</div>
```